# JSF2.0 open a pdf file of XHTML view using command button

Tags: jsf-2

I tried to export current jsf page to pdf. Code as follows:

Page with command button `index.html`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
   <h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
  </h:head>
  <h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:inputText value="#{bean.name}" id="name" ></h:inputText>
        <h:commandButton value="click" id="btn" actionListener="#{bean.writePDF}"></h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</h:body></html>
```

`writePDF()` function for action button is as follows:

```
public void writePDF() {
     String PDF_FILE_NAME = "converted.pdf";
     FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
     ExternalContext externalContext =facesContext.getExternalContext();
     HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)externalContext.getRequest();
     HttpSession session = (HttpSession) externalContext.getSession(true);
     String url = request.getRequestURL().append(";jsessionid=").append(session.getId().toString()).toString();
     try
     {
         ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
         renderer.setDocument(new URL(url).toString());
         renderer.layout();
         HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)externalContext.getResponse();
         response.reset();
         response.setContentType("application/pdf");
         response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\"" + PDF_FILE_NAME + "\"");
         ServletOutputStream browserStream = response.getOutputStream();
         ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         renderer.createPDF(browserStream);
         renderer.finishPDF();
         facesContext.responseComplete();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         ex.printStackTrace();
                  }
     facesContext.responseComplete();
 }
```

On click of command button only a blank pdf page is generating with no control and value in it.
Am I doing something wrong, kindly suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: JSF side looks fine. It'll be the iText/Flyingsaucer side which went wrong. Have you tried putting some text/images around the form? Perhaps iText/Flyingsaucer simply doesn't eat form components such as input elements and buttons. You'd then need to change the JSF rendering to present the relevant information in plain text instead of form components.

Answer (score 1):

I just did a test with exactly the given code. It indeed doesn't show anything. It turns out that Flyingsaucer simply doesn't eat HTML form elements, as already guessed in my first comment on your question.

Your best bet is really to present data by output texts instead of input texts. To achieve this dynamically, you might want to add a request parameter which triggers the conditional rendering of inputs/outputs.

E.g.

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.name}" id="name" rendered="#{not param.pdf}"/>
<h:outputText value="#{bean.name}" rendered="#{param.pdf}"/>
```

and then add a `pdf=true` to the query string.

```
String url = request.getRequestURL().append(";jsessionid=").append(session.getId()).append("?pdf=true").toString();
```

Or just create a different page which uses the same bean and then pass its URL instead.

Comment: Hi BalusC, as per solution provided by you, it is working for output texts but it was just a sample page, as per my requirement complete xhtml page view should be generated in pdf. Is there any another way to do it?

Comment: hi BalusC, I was hoping your reply on this.. can it be done if, in renderer.setDocument(content), content is html string or I have to parse xhtml and create renderer for all input control.